# Can I get an access token which accesses only unique and visits from Google api?

Tags: php, google-api, google-analytics-api

I need to get only unique, visits and page views. Right now we get access to all GA data from current token, but if we could limit the token so that we just get access to unique, visits and page views..

Comment: Hi Brother , welcome to stackoverflow :) . please explain your question furthermore , some code of what you have tried so far would certainly be a help to other people to understand what are you trying to achieve  .

Comment: In my application I need to get Google analytics data by using the access token https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtAuthorization Requested data are included lots of data, such as Unique Visits, Visits, Page Views, PrvUniqueVisits etc.. That is not safer. Can I restrict data by giving token?

Comment: I need get only Unique Visits and Visits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access tokens are used for authentication once you have access to a Google analytics account you can request all of the data associated with that account. There is no way to limit the data you have access to.

Data is limited by changing the request you make to the API.

Comment: Hi DaImTo.Thanks for your reply.Do you know any document or web link regarding this question?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-php

Comment: Hi Dalmto do you know any web link which is included with your answer (Data is limited by changing the request you make to the API)?

Comment: You could read the documentation yourself you know https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters